# Segmentation fault in C when passing argument to a function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am new to this forum, so please bear with me.

I am currently writing a program that will back up specific files and each time it is backed up a date and time stamp are added to the file name. At this stage I am writing a function that will identify all the files in the present working directory and will then read it into an array and will later on back up each of those files. The backing up works fine.

The problem I am having is that each time I attempt to pass a folder name to my function (as a string) I get a segmentation fault the debugger gives this error:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400b48 in backupAllFiles (
    dirname=) at processing.c:52
52  {

The backupAllFiles() function is written inside the processing.c source file (it is a multi-source file project). Here is a snippet of the code that is the main concern:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <getopt.h>

void backupAllFiles(char *dirname)
{
    int numfiles = 0;   
    char allFiles[MAXPATHLEN][MAXPATHLEN];  

    DIR                     *dirp;
    struct dirent *dp;

    dirp = opendir(dirname);
    if(dirp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open: %s.\n",dirname);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((dp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
    {
        struct stat stat_buffer;

        if(stat(allFiles[numfiles], &stat_buffer) != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"An error occurred while reading the directory: %s\n",dirname);
        }
        else if(S_ISREG(stat_buffer.st_mode))
        {
            sprintf(allFiles[numfiles], "%s%s", dirname, dp->d_name);
        }
        numfiles++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numfiles; i++)
    {   
        fprintf(stderr,"All the files are (%i) %s.\n",i ,allFiles[i]); 
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Entered main, passing argument %s to backupAllFiles()\n",argv[1]);
    backupAllFiles(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Please note this is not part of the main program yet, this is merely a separated segment which is used for individual testing.

I am really stumped as to why the segfault occurs and I have tried strdup for argv[1], however to no avail.

I appreciate all and any help. :)

P.S. There will be extra inclusions that are not necessary, this is for the rest of the program, I was too lazy to find which would exclusively apply to this function.

Comment: What's `MAXPATHLEN`?  Are you overflowing your stack?

Comment: `if(stat(allFiles[numfiles], &stat_buffer) != 0)` at this moment allFiles[][] is still uninitialised.

Comment: MAXPATHLEN is a constant supplied in one of the headers #include<sys/param.h> it just limits the maximum path length of any file location.

Comment: allFiles has been initialised earlier in the function, the segfault occurs even before any initialisations have been done, I used fprintf(stderr,"Started function backupAllFiles\n") as the first line of the function and it never reaches it, it terminates the program before this point.

Comment: I can reproduce the error on an Ubuntu machine from this source code. According to gdb, the segmentation fault occurs as soon as `backupAllFiles` is invoked: `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004006e8 in backupAllFiles (
    dirname=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffffeffe3d8>) at backup.c:13` This seems to me like a legitimate puzzle.

Comment: `allFiles has been initialised earlier in the function,` On which line ?

Comment: I agree, because argv[1] or any combination thereof works with all other functions that I have tested before except for this one, that is the reason why I am stumped, I didn't free that memory so I am (according to my limited experience) not trying to access that memory. As mentioned before I have used strdup() which uses malloc to duplicate a string and passed the duplicate to the function, still to no avail. I am using an Ubuntu 13.10 OS.

Comment: Is this all of your code for backupAllFiles? If not, I agree with @wildplasser that allFiles is not initialized when the if(stat(... is reached.

Comment: Think I may have misunderstood initialised, the second line after the function name says allFiles[MAXPATHLEN][MAXPATHLEN]; my intention was to say declared. My mistake.

Comment: @wildplasser, you are correct that `allFiles` has not been initialized when it is reached, but that is a red herring here. The program does not even get that far before raising a segmentation fault.

Comment: Maybe it is too large to fit into automatic memory ("on the stack") ?

Comment: Aha! I think you are exactly right. @CL4PTR4P, try changing the declaration to `char allFiles[100][100]` and running again.

Comment: @wildpasser From previous error messages using the compiler (luckily) I gathered that the size of MAXPATHLEN is about 4096 bytes, I doubt that that would overflow the stack, I just changed the dimensions to smaller values, still no results.

Comment: @qwrrty I changed the declaration to allFiles[100][100] still no results, I highly doubt that would come anywhere close to overflowing the stack.

Comment: Interesting. That did fix the problem on my machine.

Comment: I don't know whether the problem could be memory protection of some sort on my machine, but even something as low as allFiles[10][10] did not yield any admirable results, just another segfault. Yet using argv[] as argument works for all other functions.

Comment: Check that you are not invoking a segfault in some other part of the program, such as the uninitialized `allFiles` data that @wildplasser warned about.

Comment: @qwrrty Initialised it and still no results. I have absolutely no idea on how to proceed next.

Comment: I will try it on my other computer and see if there are any more favourable results.

Comment: @CL4PTR4P Standard debugging protocol for this kind of situation: remove all of the code from the function. *All* of it. Add it back in a few lines at a time. Rebuild after each addition to see at what point the problem recurs.

Comment: I think I may have solved the problem, it was as @wildplasser said the stack was overflowing, the dimensions were too large, I don't know why it didn't work when I changed it last time, must've gotten confused with which source files I compiled. Thanks to every one for the help, much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to recap some of the discussion into an answer: there are at least two problems with this code.

1. Declaring `char allFiles[MAXPATHLEN][MAXPATHLEN]` on the stack tries to allocate more memory than the system is willing to permit, which is why the segmentation fault is raised as soon as the code enters `backupAllFiles`.
2. The `stat` call in `backupAllFiles` accesses the `allFiles[numfiles]` element before initializing it. This should probably be

   ```
   if(stat(dp->d_name, &stat_buffer) != 0)
   ```

   rather than

   ```
   if(stat(allFiles[numfiles], &stat_buffer) != 0)
   ```

Thanks to @wildplasser and @Carl Norum for identifying that the underlying problem here was, literally, stack overflow.